# Python 3 "Lock" for both: threads and processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I have been trying to code a cache in python 3 and I want to avoid concurrency issues for both, threads and process.

I have been using `threading` for thread-safe code, and `multiprocessing` for process safety.

I can solve my problem using Lock from `threading` and Lock from `multiprocessing` at the same time.
But I was wondering if there is a "generic" Lock to do this stuff or something like that.

Thank you in advance ;-)

Comment: one lock to rule them all seems to be a pythonic way, but I don't know how to do this either

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the same class for both in-process locks, and cross-process locks. The implementations are quite different.

Your current strategy is the correct one.