# In python 3, is there a difference between threads and processes lock?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-3.9

I have a class that implements a thread lock:

```
from threading import Lock
class MyClass():
    _lock = Lock()
```

Which is used as followed in the code:

```
 with cls._lock:
     #dostuff
```

This works when I am working with multiple threads. However, I am facing a case where using multiple processes is required. I was wondering if this thread lock was enought or not.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Lock), `Lock` creates a `threading.Lock` object, which is used in my class above.

However, this old (2013) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947092/python-3-lock-for-both-threads-and-processes) says that threads and processes locks are different.

**Considering that I am not in the position to easily modify the class above, should I use a process lock myself on top of my class, or is it OK to assume the thread lock is enougth ?**

Comment: What happens for you when you try to synchronize two otherwise concurrent operations under `multiprocessing` using a `threading.Lock`?

Comment: Silly me not trying... The thread lock "does not work" (is not blocking multiple processes). Then, why is the documentation of process lock linking to thread lock ?

Comment: It returns a *proxy* to a new `threading.Lock`. At the very least, I would assume that the interface is the same, but that doesn't mean they *work* the same under the hood.

Comment: Be sure to read about [proxy objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-proxy-objects) as well.

Comment: @chepner got it ! If you can make an answer explaining my misunderstanding about the doc and about the proxy stuff, I'll accept it.